# When using vscode with cmake, a cmake error occurs

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using vscode with cmake for debug on a windows system, but task.json executes to the cmake command with this error:

```
`Executing task: D:\Cmake\bin\cmake.exe .. -G 'MinGW Makefiles' 

CMake Error: Could not create named generator 'MinGW Makefiles'`
```

Here is the command for cmake in my task.json file:

```
"options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/"
            },
            "label": "cmake",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [
                "..",
                "-G 'MinGW Makefiles'"
            ]
```

How exactly should I write the args `-G MinGW Makefiles`?

Comment: These are two arguments, not a single one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Looking at the error message, I don't think that's the problem. @hello CPP, can you check that [`mingw32-make`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html) is properly installed on your system?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem relates to the argument resolution of `cmd.exe`.
The command line you are trying to execute looks like this:

> cmake .. "-G 'MinGW Makefiles'"

VSCode detects that there is a space between `-G` and `'MinGW Makefiles'` and quotes this. Because arguments with spaces on Windows commandline have to be quoted. CMake does detect the `-G` at the argument beginning and tries to determine the value behind it. The value is `'MinGW Makefiles'` (including the apostrophes). As this is no valid CMake generator string the generator "cannot be created".

You have to fix your CMake argument list. This should do the trick.

```json
"args": [
    "-G", "MinGW Makefiles",
    ".."
]
```

The resulting commandline will look like this:

> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..